# Remove quotes from stdout. Pass string as file path

Tags: shell-script, zsh

I was trying to create a bookmark file for my configs, and search for them using `fzf`.
I tried both these methods but with no avail.

```
editconf() { nvim $(cat /home/anupam/scripts/conflist | fzf) }
editconf() { cat /home/anupam/scripts/conflist | fzf | xargs nvim }
```

The problem that's occurring is it's passing the path say `'~/.config/nvim/init.vim'` as a string instead of a file path `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`.

and `nvim` thinks that it's the file name instead of file path.

Any way of solving this.

PS I tried to remove the quotes using `tr` didn't work.

Comment: It's likely that the problem isn't whatever you think it is, but the `~` there. Tilde expansion is done by the shell. Neovim might do it when using `:e`, `:tabe`, etc., but not when it's passed literally as an argument. Try with `/home/anupam` instead of `~`.

Comment: Thanks that actuall solved that.

Comment: Should be `editconf() { nvim ${(f)"$(</home/anupam/scripts/conflist fzf)"}; }`. `$(...)` splits on all `$IFS` characters while you likely want to split on newline only (or not at all in which case that would be `editconf() { nvim "$(< /home/anupam/scripts/conflist fzf)"; }`. In any case con`cat`enating a single file doesn't make much sense, `cat` is redundant here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for pointing that out I will make those changes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that ~ tilde does not expand in the shell, specifing the full path did the job.